# How to write a mongodb select query using (in) with C#

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, mongodb-query

In Sql:

```
SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE status in ("A", "D")
```

MongoDB:

```
db.inventory.find( { status: { $in: [ "A", "D" ] } } )
```

How to write above mentioned query in C# with mongoDB.i am new in mongodb.Please any one help me.
Thanks in advance.